# How to add column in AspnetUser in ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I have created  a class Application User with following properties:

```
 public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
 {
    public string RandomPassword { get; set; }
 }
```

And I have updated startup as:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

But I am getting migration to be empty.I want RandomPassword as column of AspNetUser table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your are presumably missing this definition in the DbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
   // omitted 
}
```